# Can a transformed Saiyan lower his ki to base-human level when transformed?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In Dragon Ball Resurrection of Freezer, Goku, when transformed in Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan, is almost killed by a laser beam from Sorbet. Now how could this happen? Was his ki so low even when he was a SSGSS? Later in the Dragon Ball Super series this seems to be corrected because he isn't transformed when he is hit. But then again, I don't know which is the version that counts, supposedly the manga is over the movie and series but between something that happens in the movie and series I don't know.

Then the question of this topic is: can a transformed Saiyan (Super Saiyan, Super Saiyan God, etc.) lower his ki to base-human level when transformed? Was this just a mistake or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are kind of multiple issues wrapped into one here. Firstly,

> Can a super saiyan their ki to the point that it is human level?

No that is impossible. Why? Because it takes a great amount of energy to undergo and sustain a physical transformation. If you drop your ki below a certain point. You revert to your base form.

> Goku death by beam?

Yes that can also happen. It seems almost impossible in theory but remember saiyans are in fact humanoid aliens and as such they can fall vulnerable to being shot in the back if they lower their ki sense. Whis warns Goku of this when he tells him during their training and in the manga that he gets too overconfident easily and lowers his guard and that is his weakness which is the polar opposite of Vegeta who is too on-guard and thus gets slowed down. (I can link the manga panel later).

The point is. Goku was confident of victory which is why he was able to be shot.

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick too much here, but his confidence was not the actual cause of the injury. His confidence directly caused him to drop his defenses, and that is what left him vulnerable to the attack. Without his defenses up, he has only his raw body strength to resist the attack, and though we all know he could easily take bullets with that body, it cant deal with any Ki attacks.

Comment: But he wasn't shot with a ki based attack. He was shot with a plasma rifle by Frieza's henchman.

Answer (score 0):

The comment marked as answer is WRONG. Re-watch the Cell Saga, especially after Goku and Gohan leave the time chamber. Whether or not their powered down super saiyan form is to the level of a "human" is debatable, but the characters did mention Goku and Gohan seemed like normal people. Later on, we saw that for Gohan to get to SSj2, was to make SSj1 feel like your normal state.

*removed the word Necessary. There are the DBZ encyclopedia books out there, it said you needed more anger to reach SSJ2 from SSj1-so I apologize for that.

Comment: When was it established that you need SSJ1 to be nearly your normal state to achieve SSJ2. Vegeta was not able to do so when he went Majin and attained SSJ2. Goku and Gohan trained to maintain SSJ1 for longer periods of time so that they could conserve energy for the fight against cell. Goku was at the same level as Gohan regarding SSJ1 feeling normal, but he was no where near being able to go SSJ2, while Gohan was.

Comment: Until the first SSJ2 transformation, NO ONE went from normal to SSJ2. They were always in SSJ1 first, then SSJ2, then SSJ3. After the first time someone transformed, they "learned" how to do it, then could skip levels. \

Comment: You did not answer the question. Why Gohan can skip SSJ1 and go to SSJ2 is completely unrelated to the requirements to obtain SSJ2, which you seem to know more than the wiki since it directly disagrees with you and the requirement you listed.

Comment: Gohan never skipped ssj1........are you watching the show or reading only?

Comment: "they 'learned' how to do it, then could skip levels" That would be your line of thought, not mine. Your the one who was talking about skipping levels. (and you should know i was talking about Powering up which is exactly what you were talking about, not attaining new levels. Only Gotenks got to skip SSJ2 in any way like that, but that was due to the fusion). You Still have not addressed my original concern either, opting instead to force extended discussion, which is against Stack Exchange rules.

Comment: I think you have ignored my original answer, asked something else, and now are accusing me of breaking the rules. "Can a transformed saiyan lower his ki to base-human level when transformed?" I answered the original question, you added stuff about not needing to be SSJ1. Goku goes SSj3  from a normal state against super buu. Ok-the word "necessary". Are you done now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48684/discussion-between-ryan-and-king-of-nes).

Comment: In the buu arc Goku went over each transformation before he went ssj3. You say ssj needs to feel like a normal state for ssj2. But that's not actually the case. As stated in the wiki here. http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_2 In order to reach ssj2 you need to have a large amount of energy way beyond what is needed for ssj.

Comment: I had to edit my answer, since it seems to be such a big deal, more so than the question itself. I'm done talking about this topic, it has exceeded my entertainment time for today. Bottom line, they DID lower their power while in SSJ form. SSJ2 requires everything that SJ1 requires + more, and SSJ3 requires everything from SSJ2 + more. Thank you